# Localization of Game Score Data displays incorrectly (see image)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization, facebook-timeline

The thousands separator in Turkish is '.' and I believe this is causing some issues with the display of player scores using the new Scores API.

The screen shot (link) below is from a Turkish player ("locale": "tr_TR") and I'm passing his score as an integer (eg: 9800 ) points.

[image: Screenshot]

The first problem is that the new score is being truncated after the '.', showing only '9' points and not (for example) 9800.

The second (and more minor) problem is that apparently 4 digit numbers should not have a thousands separator in them, only 5 digits and above.

(This is my first stackoverflow post so please be gentle. Cheers)